# Routing in Windows

Tags: networking, routing

Initially (just after system startup) the ip table is like that:

```
192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.0.11    276
192.168.0.11   255.255.255.255       On-link      192.168.0.11    276
192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255       On-link      192.168.0.11    276
```

and when i run netcat:

> nc -zv -s 192.168.0.11 192.168.0.11 80

to test if port 80 is open it works - the port 80 is indeed open. But when i remove the 192.168.0.11 route i got "TIMEOUT" on nc test. Shouldn't it pick 192.168.0.0 route and work? Moreover when i add the route manually:

route add 192.168.0.11 mask 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0 it still doesn't work!

---

Can someone else try to provide me eventually an usefull answer?

Answer (score 1):

The system adds the address of the local interface so the routing table should know that any traffic addressed to this IP address it shouldn't be sent out on the network.

Comment: Yes i konw that but why is't it working when i manually add previously deleted route ?

Comment: Can You please answer my question?

Answer (score 1):

0.0 is a network address and 0.255 is a broadcast address. The only valid actually usable IP address listed there is 0.11.

So no, what you are attempting will not work.

Comment: but 192.168.0.11 belongs to 192.168.0.0 network so why don't it pick 192.168.0.0 route if 192.168.0.11 is removed?

Comment: Can You please answer my question?

Comment: The packets have nowhere valid to go if you don't have at least one working address in that subnet.

Comment: I don't understand. Why do You say i don't have any working address?  All i deleted is just a route not just 0.11 interface.

Comment: Can You please answer my question?

Comment: Can You be so kind to return to that old question and answer it? I really need to clarify that! Thx.

Comment: What is unclear ? You cannot practically route to a network address. In order for a route to exists, it needs a valid destination, which you don't have, since you only had one valid address and you removed it.

Comment: But 192.168.0.11 belongs to 192.168.0.0 so shouldn't it be selected in case of 192.168.0.11 route absence?

Comment: When you travel by car, you to that to arrive to a destination, you do not travel a road with no destination.